# Firebase storage getDownloadURL() doesn't return a working url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I tried to use `getDownloadURL()` method to retrieve the url of my images which stored in firebase storage.

Weird is it returns a url which is an object, instead of images

↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓EXAMPLE URL↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/example.appspot.com/o/images%2Fcat.png
↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑EXAMPLE URL↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑

I did some research online and found out the correct url to display my image should be like this...

↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓EXAMPLE URL↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/example.appspot.com/o/images%2Fcat.png?alt=media&token=sometoken
↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑EXAMPLE URL↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑

But I have no clue how to get the url by using `getDownloadURL()`...

Here's my code...

```
var storage = firebase.storage();

$scope.getImgUrl = function(file) {
    storage.ref("images/" + file + ".png")
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then(function onSuccess(url) {
        return url;
      })
      .catch(function onError(err) {
        console.log("Error occured..." + err);
      })
  }
```

Any idea?

Comment: These urls return error 404

Comment: The ?alt=media&token=sometoken aren't necessary.

Comment: The url does not work. `Not Found.  Could not access bucket example.appspot.com`

Comment: Did you get the right response. i am still stuck with this

Answer (score 6):

So the correct way to get an image url from Firebase is this:

```
 $scope.getImgUrl = function(file) {
        storage.child("images/" + file +".png").getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
          return url;
        }).catch(function(error) {
          // Handle any errors here
        });
 }
```

Note that you are using `storage.child()` instead of `storage.ref()`

Comment: I tried, but still no luck... I guess I will just put them in database to get a easier access by angularfire... thanks anyway!

Comment: Is it still returning an object?

Comment: VM4235 CommonService.js:312 Uncaught TypeError: firebase.storage(...).child is not a function
    at Object.uploadImage (VM4235 CommonService.js:312)
    at updateSubCategory (SubCategoryController.js:84)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (SubCategoryController.js:68)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
uploadImage @ VM4235 CommonService.js:312
updateSubCategory @ SubCategoryController.js:84
(anonymous) @ SubCategoryController.js:68
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3

Answer (score 4):

The return you have in the `then()` callback doesn't do what you expect it to do. When you call `getDownloadUrl()` it returns a promise. If you simply bind that promise to the scope, you can use it in your HTML:

```
$scope.getImgUrl = function(file) {
    return storage.ref("images/" + file + ".png").getDownloadURL();
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I read a lot of answer from you on stackoverflow XD. But this time I still cant figure out what's going wrong. I'll just use the database to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
firebase.storage().ref().child('Audios/file.wav').getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
                        console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
 });
```

Comment: adding an explanation to your answer would make for a better understanding

Answer (score 0):

I was also stumbling around with the same problem a couple years later in 2020 xD 
turns out... I just had to configure my firebase security to public when I'm testing from this

```
// Only authenticated users can read or write to the bucket
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

to this, in the firebase rules tab

```
// Only authenticated users can read or write to the bucket
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the below code works for me. it works for video files and images.

```
var ref = firebase.storage().ref().child('child');
var file = document.querySelector("#htmlInputTagID").files[0];
var task = ref.child(('file name').toString()).put(file);
var imgURL = "";
task.then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
        imgURL = url;//this is the URL I use and it works 
        //for me it can be done also for video files
    });
});
```