# AngularFire2 getDownloadURL() returns json

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I am following these code samples: https://blog.angular.io/file-uploads-come-to-angularfire-6842352b3b47

I upload an image.
The task gives me a URL. I click it, and it works great.

When I try to retrieve the URL later using:

```
# controller
var imageUrl = this.firestorage.ref( data.primaryImage.storageRef ).getDownloadURL();

# template
<ng-template *ngIf="knife.imageUrl | async; let url">
  <img mat-card-image [src]="url">
</ng-template>
```

The response is HTTP 200, but it only gives me back json describing the file, with name, bucket, etag, etc.

The difference between the two requests is that in the working one the query parameter `?alt=media` is appended to the URL.

How can I force angularfire/angular to use this query parameter, or otherwise get the desired effect of returning the actual image instead of metadata?

Would it be better to keep a handle of the downloadURL and ignore the storageRef?

Using:

- Angular 5.2.3
- AngularFire2 5.0.0-rc.6

Comment: your storage ref should end with image extension like `.ref('/users/davideast.png').getDownloadURL()`

Comment: I tried this as well; but using jpg file. No difference. I can also confirm that the object has "contentType": "image/jpeg" in storage

Comment: Also found parallel question for angular.js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40364281/firebase-storage-getdownloadurl-doesnt-return-a-working-url